Unity 3D RidgidBody.AddForce doesn't move
I have the following object and and player controller
public float speed = 50.0f;
private float turnSpeed = 45.0f;
private float horizontalInput;
private float forwardInput;
public bool hasDelivery = false;
public bool hasPowerUp = false;
public GameManager1 gameManager;
private Rigidbody rb;
// Start is called before the first frame update
void Start()
{
    rb = GetComponent<Rigidbody>();
    gameManager = GameObject.Find("GameManager").GetComponent<GameManager1>();
}

//(0.00, 0.00, 1.34)"
void FixedUpdate()
{
    forwardInput = Input.GetAxis("Vertical");
    horizontalInput = Input.GetAxis("Horizontal");

    Vector3 movement = transform.forward * forwardInput * speed;
    rb.AddForce(movement * speed);

    float turn = horizontalInput * turnSpeed * Time.fixedDeltaTime;
    Quaternion turnRotation = Quaternion.Euler(0f, turn, 0f);

    //rb.AddTorque(transform.up * turn);
    rb.MoveRotation(rb.rotation * turnRotation);
}


When I try and move the object nothing happens. Any help would be appreciated

are your forwardInput horizontalInput variables non 0?

Because it's kinematic.

Try to change it to not be kinematic.
In Unity, a kinematic rigidbody is a type of rigidbody that is not affected by physics forces, such as gravity, but can still be moved by script or animation. Kinematic rigidbodies are often used for objects that need to be moved or controlled by the game script or animation, but do not need to be affected by physics simulations.
Here are some key points about kinematic rigidbodies in Unity:
Movement: Kinematic rigidbodies can be moved by script or animation, but are not affected by physics forces like gravity.
Collisions: Kinematic rigidbodies can still collide with other objects, but the collision will not affect their movement or position.
Constraints: Kinematic rigidbodies can be connected to other rigidbodies using joints or constraints, which can restrict their movement.
Control: Kinematic rigidbodies can be controlled by script or animation, allowing for precise movement and positioning.
Kinematic rigidbodies are commonly used in various scenarios, such as:
Game characters or NPCs that need to be moved or controlled by script or animation.
Objects that need to be moved or positioned precisely, such as puzzle pieces or interactive elements.
Objects that need to be constrained or restricted in their movement, such as doors or windows.
In summary, kinematic rigidbodies in Unity provide a way to move and control objects without being affected by physics simulations, making them a useful tool for game development and other applications.
